# Swift back button not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add back button in new ViewController.

I am opening this view controller from tabbar view with show segue.

I implemented item bar in top and add action to viewcontoller.

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
```

and add this code in it

Storyboard
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B93rd-pg4by8Q0tNWXMwTXlVanM/view

Answer (score 4):

If you are using swift 3 you have to replace`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);`
 with `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I am using swift 2

Answer (score 0):

`self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure whether you are pushing the view or presenting the view. If you are pushing the view then you have to pop it by adding this line

self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)